# Powerbuilder 7 - Only print header on first page and footer on last page

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy, powerbuilder-pfc

I need to only print header on the first page and footer on the last page. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a group in your DW which would change only as the invoice changes - say on the invoice number.  Move your header information (the stuff you only want to print on the first page of the invoice) into the group band.  Now if you have a multi page invoice the header will only print on the first page.